# Modifying graphs in 'survrec' package

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am new to R and I am using the package 'survrec'. I would like to modify the colors and lines in graphs with multiple groups. The package includes this example:

```
data(colon)
# fit a pena-strawderman-hollander and plot it
fit<-survfitr(Survr(hc,time,event)~as.factor(dukes),data=colon,type="pena")
plot(fit,ylim=c(0,1),xlim=c(0,2000))
```

Using the arguments "col" or "lty" like in other graphs or "survfit"-objects does not work.

```
plot(fit,ylim=c(0,1),xlim=c(0,2000), col=c("red", "blue", "orange"), lty=3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `palette` to impact the palette for base plots and `par` to modify other parameter defaults:

```
library(survrec)
library(viridis)

data(colon)
fit<-survfitr(Survr(hc,time,event)~as.factor(dukes),data=colon,type="pena")

palette(viridis(3))
plot(fit,ylim=c(0,1),xlim=c(0,2000))
```

[image]

```
palette(c("#7f3b08", "#2d004b", "#1b7837"))
plot(fit,ylim=c(0,1),xlim=c(0,2000))
```

[image]

```
palette(c("red", "blue", "orange"))
par(lty=3)
plot(fit,ylim=c(0,1),xlim=c(0,2000))
```

[image]

Unfortunately `survrec:::plot.survfitr` hard-codes `lty=2` for the upper/lower lines. You can make a copy of the function and parameterize that, tho, if need be.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a lot!

Comment: PS: Is there a way to set up different line types for each of the groups?

Comment: you'll have to edit the function to do that level of customization or convert the underlying data to a data frame and use ggplot2. there are some examples for the latter in https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify